# no idea why my model returns two different values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my view all function in my postcards model, in one controller it returns 4 and the other returns, no idea why, I'm echoing num_rows() to see whats going on.

Theres nothing else being passed, its exactly the same except, one view is a front for a facebook and one view is an admin section

```
function view_all(){

    $query = $this->db->get('postcards');
    echo $query->num_rows();
    $data = Array();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row){

            $data[] = $row;

        }

    }
    $query->free_result();


    return $data;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the DB connection is to the same database in the two controllers?

Comment: yes its running off the one config file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing it around a little bit to help you out:

```
function view_all(){

    $query = $this->db->get('postcards');
    echo $query->num_rows();
//    $data = Array();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row){

            $data[] = $row;

        }
    return $data;

    }
    $query->free_result();

}
```

Let me know what happens now.